# VBA script to select all cells between 2 ocurrences of variable text. Problems

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below macro to select all cells between 2 occurrences of a user defined phrase.

```
Sub FindOfficer()
Dim FindOfficer As String
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
FindOfficer = InputBox("Enter Officer's Name")
If Trim(FindOfficer) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J:M")
        Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindOfficer, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        Set Rng2 = .Find(What:=FindOfficer, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        Set Rng3 = .Range(Rng1.Address & ":" & Rng2.Address)
        If Not Rng3 Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng3, False
        Else
            MsgBox "Error"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

It is correctly selecting the rows i need, however it is only selecting columns B to AG whilst i would like B to AL to be selected.

Any thoughts on how i could change the code to do this? I am very new to VBA

Comment: You should avoid naming a sub and a variable exactly the same ("FindOfficer"). Not only it is confusing, but if you decide to change the sub into a function in future -- the return value is assigned to a function name -- that will cause lots of troubles if gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One of the simplest is to use R1C1 cell references in which columns are refered to by number, just like rows e.g. range B2 is cell 2,2. You can also use the Row property of a range to determine what row that range starts on. Replace this:

```
Set Rng3 = .Range(Rng1.Address & ":" & Rng2.Address)
```

with this:

```
Set Rng3 = .Range(.Cells(Rng1.Row,2), .Cells(Rng2.Row, 38))
```